# How to pass a javascript variable to C# via WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to pass a JavaScript variable called `gameData` to a C# app. The concept of it was very easy to understand but the coding very hard for me.

This is for an app I make to transfer JSON data from browser to the application. But it didn't transfer any JSON but "" or after conversion, null. What I have tried is to add the executable name to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` as 11000 to emulate IE 11. But it didn't help so I searched Stack Overflow (and some other sites) to find the solution. But every question and answer I found didn't help me and gave me the same empty string.

This code is used for browser load.

```
private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (started) // set to true when the transmit button is pressed (only that happens)
            {
                loadCompleted = true;
                json2 = Convert.ToString(webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { "gameData" })); 
                // this is where the issue occurs, this returns "" but it should return JSON ( {"title": "someTitle" ...} ).
                // json2 is a private string. gameData is a big json structure.
                Console.WriteLine(json2); // event log shows ""
                CheckCB(); // goes on but then returns RuntimeBinderException because title is null

            }
        }
```

And this code is used in CheckCB() to utilize the data.

```
dynamic json;
try
{
    json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json2); // everything is okay, until..
} catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("There was a problem parsing the received JSON.", "problem parsing json",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
    MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    return;
}
string title = Convert.ToString(json.title).Replace("/", "").Replace("\\", "").Replace("*", "").Replace(":", "").Replace("?", "").Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "").Replace("|", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("\"", ""); 
// cuts the title enough to make sure a directory can be created. 
// this is where the RuntimeBinderException error occurs.
// ...
```

My expectation for that code is for the code to continue through the rest of the program (I didn't show it here, as it might be pretty useless in that topic). But actually it justs "ignores" the variable and returns "", which then converts into null and the "title" property can't be get from the dynamic object causing the program to crash.

Comment: So, the page is inside a WinForms WebBrowser Control ? Or something else, but similar?

Comment: Yes, it's a WebBrowser control which is hidden because the only purpose I used it is just to get the variable.

Comment: Er, wait. You are loading a webpage into a hidden browser control, so you can execute some javascript and retrieve the result? Is that correct?

Comment: No code is executed - just there is a global variable in that webpage and I want to load it to the json2 string.